# How to improve this complex query?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

My query is running very long. I tried to improve the query performance by adding index on `website_id` in `hh_hits` table.

Query:

```
SELECT

    w.state, xx.pretty_name, xx.member_id,
    SUM(ce.total_charge) as total_charge,
    SUM(ce.shipping_cost) as shipping_cost,
    SUM(ce.product_price * product_count) as product_price,
    SUM(ce.tax) as tax,
    SUM(ce.service_charge) as service_charge,
    COUNT(distinct ce.order_id) as order_count,
    SUM(ce.product_count) as product_count,
    SUM( (select sum(addon_price*addon_count)
             from wow.cart_entry_addons_archive cean
              where cean.cart_entry_id=ce.cart_entry_id
                and cean.addon_type='xx'
              group by ce.cart_entry_id)) as giftwrap_total,
    sum( (select sum(addon_price*addon_count)
              from wow.cart_entry_addons_archive cean2
              where cean2.cart_entry_id=ce.cart_entry_id
                and cean2.addon_type='xx'
              group by ce.cart_entry_id)) as addon_total,
    (select sum(number) as hits
              from wow.hh_hits thts
              where thts.website_id=xx.website_id
                and thts.start_date >= 'xxx'
                and thts.start_date <= 'xx') as visits

FROM

    wow.carts_archive c,
    wow.cart_entries_archive ce,
    eoe.websites xx

WHERE

    ce.order_date >= 'xx' and
    ce.order_date <= 'xx' and
    ce.website_id=xx.website_id and
    lower(ce.status) != 'deleted' and
    ce.order_status != 'cancelled' and
    ce.cart_id = c.cart_id and
    (c.cc_number <> '343334' or c.cc_number is null)
GROUP BY ce.website_id
ORDER BY ce.website_id;
```

Explain plan:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref                       | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ce    | range  | id1_nn,idx_726   | idx_1049 | 9       | NULL                      |    33 | Using where; Using filesort                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | w     | ref    | idx_1055         | idx_1055 | 5       | wow.ce.website_id         |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY  | 4       | eoe.ce.cart_id            |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | thts  | ALL    | hh_n1            | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                      | 24493 | Using where                                  |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cean2 | ref    | idx_1383         | idx_1383 | 4       | wow.ce.cart_entry_id      |     1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cean  | ref    | idx_1383         | idx_1383 | 4       | wow.ce.cart_entry_id      |     1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

Query explain plan seems `hh_hits` table is not using indexes.

Comment: what is your db engine? Mysql or Sql?

Comment: Mysql and db engine is innodb.

Comment: @Lucky: normally a question of this kind would be tagged as both (since MySQL SQL is also SQL). However the `sql` tag requests that it is used only for ANSI SQL questions, so your edit was correct.

Answer (score 0):

On hh_hits, add this compound index:

```
INDEX(website_id, start_date)
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables.

If my suggestion does not help enough, then we should talk about building a Summary Table that contains the subtotals for each website-date pair.  You would augment the table each night, then run the dependent subquery against it.